# how to solve "You have already purchased this subscription. tap buy to renew or extend it." in non-renewing subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an In-App Purchase product that is non-renewable. When somebody buys this product some content is unlocked for one month (there is nothing to be downloaded or installed).

After one month the user is asked to buy again the non-renewable product, i.e: the user need to buy that non renewable product a second time.

The problem is that when he try to do it the (testing) user got the following message:
**You have already purchased this subscription. tap buy to renew or extend it.**

Comment: So didn't get any answer?

Comment: how did you solve this? I have the exact same issue and have to create multiple individual products, manually...